# Split text file contents with Regular Expressions for delimiters?

Tags: regex, arrays, vbscript, split

I have a text file containing the results of a zone transfer & need to read each line & split it into an array to output a list of server names & IP addresses.  However I'me having some problems splitting the data as my attempt at the whitespace delimiter doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to.

Sample input:

```
machine1.fqdn.com. 86400    IN A    192.168.1.10 
machine2.fqdn.com. 86400    IN A    192.168.1.11 
machine3.fqdn.com. 86400    IN A    192.168.1.12 
machine4.fqdn.com. 86400    IN A    192.168.1.13
```

Script:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("I:\testHarvestIF.txt", ForReading)

Const ForReading = 1

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strNextLine = objFile.Readline
arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine," ",-1,1)
Wscript.Echo "Server name: " & arrServiceList(0) & vbCrLF & _ 
  " - IP Address: " & arrServiceList(2)
Loop

objFile.Close
```

Current Output:

```
Server name: machine1.fqdn.com.
IP Address: IN A    192.168.1.10
Server name: machine2.fqdn.com.
IP Address: IN A    192.168.1.11
Server name: machine3.fqdn.com.
IP Address: IN A    192.168.1.12
Server name: machine4.fqdn.com. 
IP Address: IN A    192.168.1.13
```

Desired output:

```
Server name: machine1.fqdn.com.
IP Address: 192.168.1.10
Server name: machine2.fqdn.com.
IP Address: 192.168.1.11
Server name: machine3.fqdn.com.
IP Address: 192.168.1.12
Server name: machine4.fqdn.com.
IP Address: 192.168.1.13
```

Is there some way I could use a regular expresion to use any length of whitespace as a delimiter?  E.g.

```
arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine,"^\s+",-1,1)
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Regards,

RB

Answer (score 0):

This might not work, depending on the format of your data, but you could try replacing the extra whitespace with a single space character before calling `Split`:

```
Dim re : Set re = New RegExp
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "\s+"

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strNextLine = re.Replace(objFile.Readline, " ")
arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine," ",-1,1)
Wscript.Echo "Server name: " & arrServiceList(0) & vbCrLF & _ 
  " - IP Address: " & arrServiceList(4)
Loop
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the RegExp object ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx#scripting05_topic2)) to match the required string instead of spliting the string:

```
    set regex = new RegExp
    regexp.pattern = "^.*? "
    set serverName = regex.execute(inputText).value
    regex.pattern = " .*?$"
    set ipAddress = regex.execute(inputText).value
```

Comment: I'm sorry about my previous answer. I looked into it and it turned out that vbscript doesn't support extracting the capturing groups from the Match objects. (<-verify me)

Comment: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("I:\test.txt", ForReading)
Const ForReading = 1

Function splitRE(strSource, pattern)
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern =pattern
        splitRE = Split(.Replace(strSource, " "), " ")
    End With
End Function 
    
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
   strNextLine = objFile.Readline
   arrServiceList=splitRE (strNextLine, "\s+")
   Wscript.Echo "Server name: " & arrServiceList(0) & " - IP Address: " & arrServiceList(4)
Loop
objFile.Close